# Performing user authentication in a CodeIgniter controller constructor?

Tags: security, mvc, codeigniter

In "[The Clean Code Talks -- Unit Testing](http://youtu.be/wEhu57pih5w)", Miško Hevery mentions that "as little work as possible should be done in constructors [to make classes more easily testable]'. It got me thinking about the way I have implemented my user authentication mechanism.

Having delved into MVC development through CodeIgniter, I designed my first web application to perform user authentication for protected resources *in controllers' constructors* in cases where *every* public function in that controller requires the user to be authenticated.

For controllers with public methods having mixed authentication requirements, I would naturally move the authentication from the constructor to each method requiring authentication (though I don't currently have a need for this).

I made this choice primarily

1. to keep the controller tight, and
2. to ensure that all resources in the controller are always covered.

As for code longevity and maintainability: given the application structure, I can't foresee a situation in which one of the affected controllers would need a public method that didn't require user authentication, but I can see this as a potential drawback *in general* with this implementation (i.e., requiring future refactoring).

Is this a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I do too.

The simplicity of the code for checking authenticaton in the construct is more favorable to me  (the construct is not too fat either).

I check the minimal permission required in the construct and individual permissions in the individual methods.

If all the method of the controller require same and only minimal permissions, i just put them in the construct.

One other form of the implementation is separating the controller for Authenticated users.

The backend controllers would extend 'Admin_Controller' which checks authentication in its construct, thereby restricting any operations it the user is not authenticated.

This makes the code more reusable and reliable.